# Asking for an advance on salary after being offered a relocation package?

Tags: job-offer, relocation

I have an offer from a company. The company say that they offer a relocation package which includes help with finding an apartment, and reimbursement for costs such as flight, luggage etc. There is no mention of relocation support for housing costs (i.e. rent, deposit).
Is it okay to ask them if they can loan me the costs for the first month's rent? Or am I risking the offer being retracted by making them think I am not grateful they offered a relocation package?

Comment: I presume you are still young and at the start of your career? It's normal to not have savings when you start out.

Comment: @Benjamin Yes this would be my first full time position after university. I had an internship between now and then. I already responded to the relocation offer that asked if it would work for me by saying that I am grateful for the opportunity and the help, thanking them for offering the relocation package and saying that I appreciate it and that it will be very helpful. I chickened out on asking them if they could loan me money in the form of my salary, for the first month's rent and maybe the deposit too. It would be my first permanent job and I am terrified of losing it by asking questions.

Answer (score 1):

Just be honest with them.

Tell them that you are very grateful for the opportunity and the help, and since you need to pay the new deposit before you will get the old one back you want to ask them to loan you some money.

This way, you make sure that they understnad that you are happy about the transfer and also explain why you need the money.

Comment: Thanks. I have a few things to mention. There is no old deposit, and what do you mean by transfer?

Comment: Wait, by transfer do you mean going to work for the new company?

Comment: @sa2 he probably means transfer as, the new job / position / new company. He's assuming you're moving from one rental to another, where typically you have to put down a deposit. If you move, it's a common problem that, you need additional money up front to cover the deposit on the new place, even though theoretically if you paid one at the last place you'd get it back. If you didn't pay one at the last place that's okay too. I would just ask them, and explain that you don't have all of the cash up front to complete the move... Or perhaps just take out a personal loan if possible

Comment: @schizoid04 thanks, but I think that would imply I cannot accept the offer unless they loan me the first month's rent.

Comment: @Sa2 - You will be amazed what concessions renters will make to fill a vacancy. Having a job offer and proving your ability to pay your rent often will go a long way. You just have to ask for concessions, a full term signed lease, is better than an empty apartment.  All you need to do is ask your potential, what would they need so you can prove, you have the ability to pay them once you get paid in the future.

Comment: Donald, do you think your comment deserves to be it's own answer?

Comment: @Sa2 do you work in tech, where the job market is hot? (guesstimate from you other question) If so, they will likely be more than happy to give you an advance. It's costs them basically nothing, the risk you will default on a one months salary is basically nil. And if they give you the advance, that will likely increase your loyality because they were accomodating. So it's win/win.

Comment: @Benjamin Yes I work in tech but the offer is for an entry level position. Thanks for the encouraging comment. I will go ahead and ask if they can loan me money (an advance on salary) which I will use for the first month's rent and deposit. I already tried asking if I could start by working remotely until my first salary when I could afford to pay the first month's rent and deposit required for the move, but understandably that is not allowed. Is it okay to send the email asking for an advance on salary today which is a Saturday or should I wait till Monday?

Comment: I don't know if using Saturday to send emails negotiating a job offer is looked down on.

Comment: Unless you work in a place where saturday is holy and people are very religious, I'd say no, it's fine. Send it, don't expect an answer prior to monday though. it's very common to do stuff like this outside working hours, so people generally do jobchanging stuff late in the day or on weekends.

Comment: @Benjamin - No; It’s advice at best; There really isn’t any way I could make that statement into an answer.  As for sending an email on Saturday, many people check their work email on Saturday (especially managers actively looking to fill a position), but many don’t so worst case it’s at the top of their inbox on Monday.  You might even get a response before that but don’t expect it.

Comment: @Benjamin all well so far after asking for an advance on salary :). They will check with their colleagues and maybe let me know tomorrow about whether they give it or not. However, last week I told them that today I would get back to them regarding the offer letter which is time sensitive, but I don't want to accept the offer letter before they get back to me about the advance on salary, even though I will accept the offer whether they give the advance on salary or not. How can I tell them that I will respond to the offer letter when I hear back from them about the advance on salary?