# How to respectfully decline offer from previous employer

Tags: employer-relations, employer, layoff

My previous employer wants me to come work for them again. I was let go because of the pandemic, but I think the real reason I was let go is because my line manager had issues with my communication, that was the feed back he gave me after I was told I was being let go.

I don't want to work for my previous employer again even though I enjoyed it and we still have a great relationship and I am still in contact with them (i.e. the heads of the company).

How do I politely and respectfully tell my previous employer that I don't want to work for them again, without burning bridges and damaging our good relationship?

Edit: from the comments:
I have been interviewing with other companies, and want to move forward. I guess it is like not wanting to get back with an ex after a breakup because meeting new people is better.

Comment: Do you have another job right now? If so, this is easy: "Thanks for the offer, but I'm happy in my new role."

Comment: @Philip Kendall No I don't have a job right now, and I mentioned this to one of the heads recently, so they know I am not working at the moment.

Comment: @Joe Strazzere That seems abrupt. Well they will write references for me and provide a letter of recommendation. All this being said I want to continue our good relationship and don't want my response to come across as snubby or negative in any way. I don't want to jeopardize the good relationship I have with them.

Comment: if you have contact with one of the heads, could you arrange to work under another line manager? could you talk through this with one of the heads of company? or in other words: could you use your relationship with the heads to remove any obstacles you see from working there?

Comment: @Benjamin Any issues I had with the line manager were due to my inexperience. He was generally a good manager and I don't have anything against him. Even then, the line manager is one of the heads at the company so even if I did have an issue with him I would not be able to request not to work under him.

Comment: Is it possible to work with that linemanager through communication problems. Commumincation is a very common problem early on in careers, and it's great to improve that early! If they were willing to work with you on that, this could be an opportunity for you. (I am working so hard to see if this could work after all, because you said you enjoyed it and still have good relations). Maybe you can expand on why you don't want to work there anymore too.

Comment: @Benjamin I have been interviewing with other companies, and want to move forward. I guess it is like not wanting to get back with an ex after a breakup because meeting new people is better.

Comment: They want you back even though there were communcation problems obviously bad enough for them to let you go? If I was in your situation the first thing I did is to ask what's really going on there. If you know that you can address it and give a well founded answer why you are no longer interested. Or perhaps some misunderstandings are cleared and you change your mind.

Comment: Am I right that the real question here is "how do I maintain a good *personal/social* relationship with an ex-employer, whilst declining any further employment with them"? You mention "burning bridges" whilst making it clear that actually the employment bridge is one you don't ever intend to cross again, so it must be some other bridge. (1/2)

Comment: Honesty may be the best policy - simply admit that you're being paid more, or doing a wider variety of work, etc. You draw the analogy with an ex, and whereas it's hardly placatory to an ex to say "I'm enjoying sex with a much wider variety of people than before" or "my new partner is more attractive", it seems perfectly feasible to say to an ex-employer "I think my salary has grown too far beyond your normal ranges", or "I'm enjoying a wider variety of work challenges, and can't return to the familiar", or even "I'm getting on too well with my immediate colleagues to consider moving". (2/2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally, following sentence is perfectly valid:

Thank you, but I am currently not interested. I will let you know if this changes.

But since you have great relations with them, and I presume you talk about other things too and maybe even have a sort of friendship, you might be inclined to give a reason.

Thank you for your offer, I really enjoyed working with you. But right now, I want to grow into another direction.

If you really have a friendship with them, you should think about something you want they can't possibly provide. That way, you not coming back is on you, not on them, and they should be understanding.

Comment: Your last paragraph is exactly what I need. (At the moment) I don't want to work with the technology my previous company uses. I think I'll use this, thanks.

Comment: Just to make sure: You should follow through with that. If you give a reason, and than contradict that by how you take a job, that will backfire. I had a coworker who left because he wanted to work closer to home (-> less commute). Later on I found his new job was even further away from home, that's when I realized he talked BS. This costs a lot of trust.

Comment: I'm really impressed by your answer. Do you mind writing an answer or comment to my other question https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/173985/asking-for-an-advance-on-salary-after-being-offered-a-relocation-package . I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I'll make sure to follow through.

Comment: Sadly, I have no personal experience with that other topic and can't give a better answer than the existing one.

Answer (score 0):

> My previous employer wants me to come work for them again.

That's very good. Few employers actively reach out to ex-employees.

> but I think the real reason I was let go is because my line manager had issues with my communication,

Maybe, maybe not. If there was a real performance issue, they wouldn't ask you to come back.

> I don't want to work for my previous employer again even though I enjoyed it and we still have a great relationship and I am still in contact with them (i.e. the heads of the company).

That sounds like a contradiction. If things are good with them, why do you not want to work there.

> How do I politely and respectfully tell my previous employer that I don't want to work for them again, without burning bridges and damaging our good relationship?

*thanks for reaching out, I'm delighted to hear that you want me back. Unfortunately I'm not looking for a change at this time, so I have to decline*

ALTERNATIVE: If you genuinely liked it there and you have nothing better going on, why not give it a shot? Whatever reason prevents you from returning, it may be negotiable: money, commute, different supervisor, different role. There is really no harm in asking for it.

Comment: Thanks. What does "I'm not looking for a change" mean? I am not working at the moment and my previous employer knows this.

Comment: @Sa2 - They would not have know that unless you told them (but you revealed in a comment this did happen), so cut the part about a change and politely decline.